# Micro USB and RS485 Compatibility

Tags: usb, differential, rs485

I am looking into understanding micro usb better and seem to be missing something apparently obvious different about the difference between micro usb and rs485.

From looking online like [here](https://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb2.shtml), the differential signaling for Micro USB is +/- 200mV. Isn't this the same as RS485? Everywhere seems to indicate that I can't connect a RS485 signal to a micro usb form factor. Is it because the Micro USB wiring is 4 wire and has Vcc and Gnd while RS485 is just two wire?

Both are differential signals with +/- 200mV swings. Both typically send data in packets/are UARTs.

Comment: Differential signalling and voltage levels do not define everything about a protocol just like how having gendered nouns doesn't make two languages the same language. One glaring difference  is RS485 is half duplex. But that doesn't mean RS422 which is full duplex is compatible with USB either. It goes far beyond that. What you're doing is like trying to figure out why French isn't understood by someone who only knows English with a checklist of characteristics. "*Both typically send data in packets/are UARTs*" is kind of like saying both English and French have sentences. Means almost nothing

Comment: USB IS half-duplex (at least standard 2.0 that author refers in his post). Voltage levels ARE different, check the electrical specs of both and you will see the difference. On the RS485 you can have from -7V to +12V as a norm on both lines, that might simply kill your USB device.

Comment: they're totally different animals. If you connect an RS485 out to a USB in you will get nothing except maybe errors coming from drivers.

Comment: @AndrejsGasilovs I suppose it would have to be with only 4 pins. That's kind of amazing actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several misconceptions here. Just to be precise, MicroUSB is a connector type (an electromechanical interface) while RS-485 is a specification for an electrical interface.

MicroUSB connector itself does not define voltages. It might be 3.3V signaling for 1.5 and 12 Mbits and 400mV for 480 Mbps.

And USB data packets are not sent with UART protocol.

RS485 is also only an electrical protocol, it means voltages, it does not mean UART protocol.

RS485 reception must work down to 200mV but transmission must be 1.5V to 5V into terminated load.

So USB and RS-485 are completely different and incompatible electrically and protocol-wise too. Even if RS-485 typically uses UART in many cases, USB uses the USB protocol, LS, FS or HS are the ones available on standard USB 2.0 port.

Comment: Ok, that clears a lot up. Thanks! I was trying to figure out the protocol for USB and I must have missed it being USB protocol. I think I read or maybe was hoping it was UART somewhere (mistake on my part again) since that'd be my use case. 
When you mean 3.3V signaling, do you mean that's that differential swing? That seems pretty high (which kind of makes sense since the data rate is so slow).